# read from stdin for libxml2 in C

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, libxml2

I would like to know the best way to parse a large amount of xml from stdin (data getting piped) into a program  I am writing using `libxml2`.  I can parse fine using a reader from the function `xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlNewTextReaderFilename(filename)` when I have a `char *` to the name of the file.  I would preferably like to wind up with a reader so the rest of my program remains the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best thing to do is to use the opening function that contains a file descriptor as the parameter and pass `STDIN_FILENO`.

http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html#xmlReaderNewFd

Comment: `stdin` isn't a file descriptor (`int`), it's a file pointer (`FILE *`).  You want `STDIN_FILENO` to pass to `xmlReaderForFd()`.